# How to load new iframe vrview panorama image from json link list?

Tags: javascript, json, image, iframe, 360-panorama-viewer

I build up an website which contains on the left side an panoramic viewer ([VrView](https://developers.google.com/vr/discover/360-degree-media) from google) and right a shopping floorplan map.
I don´t know the exact way of clicking at the json link the iframe is updated with another pano picture. Can anyone help me?

I´m also not sure if the vrviewer is the best solution or better to embed three.js with the code for [panorama cube](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_cube) which works itself also great. I´m open for any suggestions. Thank you.

Here the code for the iframe version:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Pano Map</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/map.css">
</head>
<body class="stretched">
    <div id="wrap">
        <header>
            <nav></nav>
        </header>
        <section id="content">
            <!--VrView -->
            <div class="col_two_third">
                <script type='text/template'>
                    <iframe class="vrview" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="800px" src="http://mypage.com/vrview/index.html?image=http://mypage.com/vrview/image/pano01.jpg"></iframe>
                    <script>
                        function DeviceMotionSender(){if(!this.isIOS_()){return}window.addEventListener("devicemotion",this.onDeviceMotion_.bind(this),false);this.iframes=document.querySelectorAll("iframe.vrview")}DeviceMotionSender.prototype.onDeviceMotion_=function(e){var message={type:"DeviceMotion",deviceMotionEvent:this.cloneDeviceMotionEvent_(e)};for(var i=0;i<this.iframes.length;i++){var iframe=this.iframes[i];var iframeWindow=iframe.contentWindow;if(this.isCrossDomainIframe_(iframe)){iframeWindow.postMessage(message,"*")}}};DeviceMotionSender.prototype.cloneDeviceMotionEvent_=function(e){return{acceleration:{x:e.acceleration.x,y:e.acceleration.y,z:e.acceleration.z},accelerationIncludingGravity:{x:e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x,y:e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y,z:e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z},rotationRate:{alpha:e.rotationRate.alpha,beta:e.rotationRate.beta,gamma:e.rotationRate.gamma},interval:e.interval}};DeviceMotionSender.prototype.isIOS_=function(){return/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!window.MSStream};DeviceMotionSender.prototype.isCrossDomainIframe_=function(iframe){var html=null;try{var doc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;html=doc.body.innerHTML}catch(err){}return html===null};var dms=new DeviceMotionSender;
                    </script>
                </script>   
            </div>
            <!--Map -->
            <div class="col_one_third col_last clearfix">   
                <div class="map-container">
                    <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>


    <!-- Scripts -->
        <!-- Map Floorplan -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>a
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="map/map.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var map = $('#map').map({
                    source: 'maplist.json',
                    height: 800,
                    mapfill: true,
                    maxscale: 1
                });

                // EVENTS
                // Map ready
                map.on('mapready', function(e, self) {
                    console.log('Map is ready!')
                    // self grants direct access to the map object
                    // The map will be focused on the washing machine by default
                    //self.moveTo(0.67, 0.62, 3, 0);
                });

                // Location opened
                map.on('locationopened', function(e, location) {
                    // location grants full access to the location
                    console.log(location.title + ' opened.');
                });

                // Location closed
                map.on('locationclosed', function(e) {
                    console.log('Location closed.');
                });

                // Level switched
                map.on('levelswitched', function(e, level) {
                    console.log('Switched to ' + level + ' level.');
                });

                // Position changed
                map.on('positionchanged', function(e, self) {
                    // self grants direct access to the map object
                    //console.log('Pan or zoom performed, current scale: ' + self.scale);
                });

                // METHODS
                // Getting mapplic object
                var self = map.data('map');

                map.on('locationclosed', function(e) {
                    //console.log(self);
                });
            });
        </script>

        <!-- VRView code from google-->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          //<![CDATA[
          var BreakpointHandler = function() {
            this.initted = false;
            this.isHomePage = false;
            this.isMobile = false;
          };
          BreakpointHandler.prototype.finalizeSummary = function(summaryHtml, lastNode) {
            // Use $.trim for IE8 compatibility
            summaryHtml = $.trim(summaryHtml).replace(/(<br>|\s)+$/,'');
            if (lastNode.nodeType == 3) {
              var lastChar = summaryHtml.slice(-1);
              if (!lastChar.match(/[.”"?]/)) {
                if (!lastChar.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) {
                  summaryHtml = summaryHtml.slice(0, -1);
                }
                summaryHtml += ' ...';
              }
            } else if (lastNode.nodeType == 1 && (lastNode.nodeName == 'I' || lastNode.nodeName == 'A')) {
              summaryHtml += ' ...';
            }
            return summaryHtml;
          };
          BreakpointHandler.prototype.generateSummaryFromContent = function(content, numWords) {
            var seenWords = 0;
            var summaryHtml = '';
            for (var i=0; i < content.childNodes.length; i++) {
              var node = content.childNodes[i];
              var nodeText;
              if (node.nodeType == 1) {
                if (node.hasAttribute('data-about-pullquote')) {
                  continue;
                }
                nodeText = node.textContent;
                if (nodeText === undefined) {
                  // innerText for IE8
                  nodeText = node.innerText;
                }
                if (node.nodeName == 'DIV' || node.nodeName == 'B') {
                  // Don't end early if we haven't seen enough words.
                  if (seenWords < 10) {
                    continue;
                  }
                  if (i > 0) {
                    summaryHtml = this.finalizeSummary(summaryHtml, content.childNodes[i-1]);
                  }
                  break;
                }
                summaryHtml += node.outerHTML;
              } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                nodeText = node.nodeValue;
                summaryHtml += nodeText + ' ';
              }
              var words = nodeText.match(/\S+\s*/g);
              if (!words) {
                continue;
              }
              var remain = numWords - seenWords;
              if (words.length >= remain) {
                summaryHtml = this.finalizeSummary(summaryHtml, node);
                break;
              }
              seenWords += words.length;
            }
            return summaryHtml;
          };
          BreakpointHandler.prototype.detect = function() {
            var match,
                pl     = /\+/g,
                search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
                decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
                query  = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var urlParams = {};
            while (match = search.exec(query))
              urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
            this.isListPage = $('html').hasClass('list-page');
            this.isMobile = urlParams['m'] === '1';
            this.isHomePage = window.location.pathname == '/';
          };
          BreakpointHandler.prototype.initContent = function() {
            var self = this;
            $('.post').each(function(index) {
              var body = $(this).children('.post-body')[0];
              var content = $(body).children('.post-content')[0];
              $(content).addClass('post-original');
              var data = $(content).children('script').html();
              data = self.rewriteForSSL(data);
              // If exists, extract specified editor's preview.
              var match = data.match(/([\s\S]+?)<div data-is-preview.+?>([\s\S]+)<\/div>/m);
              if (match) {
                data = match[1];
              }
              // Prevent big images from loading when they aren't needed.
              // This must be done as a pre-injection step, since image loading can't be
              // canceled once embedded into the DOM.
              if (self.isListPage && self.isMobile) {
                data = data.replace(/<(img|iframe) .+?>/g, '');
              }
              // Insert template to be rendered as nodes.
              content.innerHTML = data;
              if (self.isListPage) {
                var summary = document.createElement('div');
                $(summary).addClass('post-content');
                $(summary).addClass('post-summary');
                body.insertBefore(summary, content);
                if (match) {
                  // Use provided summary.
                  summary.innerHTML = match[2];
                } else {
                  // Generate a summary.
                  // Summary generation relies on DOM, so it must occur after content is
                  // inserted into the page.
                  summary.innerHTML = self.generateSummaryFromContent(content, 30);
                }
                // Add read more link to summary.
                var titleAnchor = $(this).find('.title a')[0];
                var link = titleAnchor.cloneNode(true);
                link.innerHTML = 'Read More';
                $(link).addClass('read-more');
                summary.appendChild(link);
              }
            });
            // Firefox does not allow for proper styling of BR.
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1) {
              $('.post-content br').replaceWith('<span class="space"></span>');
            }
            $('.loading').removeClass('loading');
          };
          BreakpointHandler.prototype.process = function() {
            if (!this.initted) {
              var makeInsecureImageRegex = function(hosts) {
                var whitelist = hosts.join('|').replace(/\./g,'\\.');
                // Normal image tags, plus input images (yes, this is possible!)
                return new RegExp('(<(img|input)[^>]+?src=("|\'))http:\/\/(' + whitelist +')', 'g');
              };
              this.sslImageRegex = makeInsecureImageRegex(BreakpointHandler.KNOWN_HTTPS_HOSTS);
              this.sslImageCurrentDomainRegex = makeInsecureImageRegex([window.location.hostname]);
              this.detect();
              this.initContent();
              this.initted = true;
            }
          };
          BreakpointHandler.KNOWN_HTTPS_HOSTS = [
            "www.google.org",
            "www.google.com",
            "services.google.com",
            "blogger.com",
            "draft.blogger.com",
            "www.blogger.com",
            "photos1.blogger.com",
            "photos2.blogger.com",
            "photos3.blogger.com",
            "blogblog.com",
            "img1.blogblog.com",
            "img2.blogblog.com",
            "www.blogblog.com",
            "www1.blogblog.com",
            "www2.blogblog.com",
            "0.bp.blogspot.com",
            "1.bp.blogspot.com",
            "2.bp.blogspot.com",
            "3.bp.blogspot.com",
            "4.bp.blogspot.com",
            "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
            "lh4.googleusercontent.com",
            "lh5.googleusercontent.com",
            "lh6.googleusercontent.com",
            "themes.googleusercontent.com",
          ];
            BreakpointHandler.prototype.rewriteForSSL = function(html) {
            // Handle HTTP -> HTTPS source replacement of images, movies, and other embedded content.
            return html.replace(this.sslImageRegex, '$1https://$4')
            .replace(this.sslImageCurrentDomainRegex, '$1//$4')
            .replace(/(<(embed|iframe)[^>]+?src=("|'))http:\/\/([^"']*?(youtube|picasaweb\.google)\.com)/g, '$1https://$4')
            // Slideshow SWF takes a image host, so we need to rewrite that parameter.
            .replace(/(<embed[^>]+?feed=http(?=[^s]))/g, '$1s');
            };
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var handler = new BreakpointHandler();
            handler.process();

            function DeviceMotionSender(){if(!this.isIOS_()){return}window.addEventListener("devicemotion",this.onDeviceMotion_.bind(this),false);this.iframes=document.querySelectorAll("iframe.vrview")}DeviceMotionSender.prototype.onDeviceMotion_=function(e){var message={type:"DeviceMotion",deviceMotionEvent:this.cloneDeviceMotionEvent_(e)};for(var i=0;i<this.iframes.length;i++){var iframe=this.iframes[i];var iframeWindow=iframe.contentWindow;if(this.isCrossDomainIframe_(iframe)){iframeWindow.postMessage(message,"*")}}};DeviceMotionSender.prototype.cloneDeviceMotionEvent_=function(e){return{acceleration:{x:e.acceleration.x,y:e.acceleration.y,z:e.acceleration.z},accelerationIncludingGravity:{x:e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x,y:e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y,z:e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z},rotationRate:{alpha:e.rotationRate.alpha,beta:e.rotationRate.beta,gamma:e.rotationRate.gamma},interval:e.interval}};DeviceMotionSender.prototype.isIOS_=function(){return/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&!window.MSStream};DeviceMotionSender.prototype.isCrossDomainIframe_=function(iframe){var html=null;try{var doc=iframe.contentDocument||iframe.contentWindow.document;html=doc.body.innerHTML}catch(err){}return html===null};var dms=new DeviceMotionSender;


            // Top-level navigation.
            $(".BlogArchive .tab").click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            $(this).siblings().slideToggle(300);
            });
            $(".Label .tab").click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            $(this).siblings().slideToggle(300);
            });
            // Blog archive year expansion.
            $('.BlogArchive .intervalToggle').click(function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('collapsed');
            $(this).parent().addClass('expanded');
            } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).parent().addClass('collapsed');
            }
            });
            // Reverse order of months.
            $('.BlogArchive .intervalToggle + div').each(function(_, items) {
            var year = $(this);
            year.children().each(function(_, month) {
            year.prepend(month);
            });
            });
            // Set anchors to open in new tab.
            $('.post-content img').parent().each(function(_, node) {
            if (node.nodeName == 'A') {
            $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
            }
            });
            // Process search requests.
            $('.searchBox input').on("keypress", function(ev) {
            if (ev.which == 13) {
            window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A' + window.location.hostname + '%20' + encodeURIComponent ($(this).val());
            }
            });
            });
            //]]>
        </script>
        <script src="vrview/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*maplist.json*

```
{
    "mapwidth": "2000",
    "mapheight": "4000",
    "categories":[
        {
            "id": "floor",
            "title": "1st floor",
            "show": "true"
        },
        {
            "id": "roof",
            "title": "2nd floor",
            "show": "false"
        }
    ],
    "levels":[
        {
            "id":"floor",
            "title":"1st floor shops",
            "map":"map/images/floorplan.svg",
            "minimap": "map/images/floorplan-small.jpg",
            "locations":[
                {
                    "id": "floor001",
                    "title": "Shop A",
                    "category": "floor",
                    "link": "<iframe src=\"http://mypage.com/vrview/images/pano01.jpg\">",
                    "x": "0.4547",
                    "y": "0.1703"
                },
                {
                    "id": "floor002",
                    "title": "Shop B",
                    "category": "floor",                
                    "link": "<iframe src=\"http://mypage.com/vrview/images/pano02.jpg\">",
                    "x": "0.5814",
                    "y": "0.1703"
                },
                {
                    "id": "floor003",
                    "title": "Shop C",
                    "category": "floor",
                    "link": "<iframe src=\"http://mypage.com/vrview/images/pano03.jpg\">",
                    "x": "0.7176",
                    "y": "0.1703"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"Roof",
            "title":"2nd Floor",
            "map":"map/images/floorplan.svg",
            "minimap": "map/images/floorplan-small.jpg",
            "locations":[
                {"id": "roof001",
                    "title": "The Roof",
                    "description": "on top of this building",
                    "category": "Roof",
                    "link": "<iframe src=\"http://mypage.com/vrview/images/pano04.jpg\">",
                    "x": "0.5547",
                    "y": "0.3703"
                }

            ]
        }

    ]
}
```